# Why is the 'Physics' Stack Exchange site closing some interesting questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, close-reasons, non-mainstream-physics

I came to the *main site* for searching an interesting question about a possible universe inside atoms.

Here is a list of questions:

1. [Universe inside atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457376/)
2. [Does our Universe reside in the smallest particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241361/)
3. [One particle infinite manifestation universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249304/)

And all are closed as off-topic.

Although I am not an expert or researcher in physics, I know that these are advanced questions in physics at this point of time.

Why is our *main site* unwelcoming to those advanced questions? Is it because of the reason that the current day physics cannot answer it? Or to avoid speculations as answers?

Comment: Your first question says "many scientists raised questions" and then points to the Dalai Lama as one of those voices. To put it bluntly: the Dalai Lama is not a scientist. None of this material is science. This site, on the other hand, *is*. Hence the closures.

Answer (score 11):

Well... to put it delicately, these are not anywhere near the mainstream.  To put it less delicately, these are nutty questions.

This site is not the place to entertain this kind of unfounded speculations.

Comment: This has likely been discussed before. Can you provide some references?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You can check the tag [tag:non-mainstream-physics].

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence that unicorns do exist. There is no evidence that unicorns do not exist. Therefore we must consider the possibility of the existence of unicorns. So has any research into unicorns ever been undertaken?

This is similar to your reasoning about an atom being a “universe”.

This is not how the [scientific method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) works.